# How to convert HSL to RGB in Earth Engine (Python)?

Tags: google-earth-engine, color, google-earth-engine-python-api, rgb

I have 3 Images representing HSL (Hue, Saturation, Lightness) attributes of a single image. I would like to display them as a single RGB image, meaning I would like to create 3 separate bands with R, G, B values, respectively, based on the HSL values. I know of the `ee.Image.hsvToRgb()` function, but that's for converting HSV and not HSL, and there is no `ee.Image.hslToRgb()` function.

Is there a simple way to do this in Earth Engine using the Python API?

My current solution was taking the [HSL to RGB conversion formula from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSL_to_RGB) and reworking it step by step by generating intermediary images for chroma, x, hue', and m, while also using a **lot** of masking to translate the if-value-is-between logic to EE. But it has a very "reinventing the wheel" vibe to it, and that is usually a sign that there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HSL to HSV formula in the wikipedia page, then use hsvtorgb().